# how to assign an event to a manual table in laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, model, message

i am using a message system that has an status of not done - doing - done and i am using laravel event for Message model so when any update happens the event stores a row in message_notification table so now i want to use another event for message_notification table so upon each insert into database 1 notification would be send to admin to notify the status of message changed .
i do it untill the store of notification in database now what i need is using laravel event not on a model but on a manual made table and i wanted to know if this is possible and here is the code i have untill here so far 
this is event which is name : MessageUpdated

```
 use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

/**
 * Create a new event instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct(Message $message)
{
    $changer_id = Auth::user()->id;

    DB::table('message_notification')->insert([
        [
         'title' =>'Message Status has been changed',
         'status' =>  $message->status,
         'notification_status' => 0,
         'changer_id' => $changer_id,
         'created_at' => DB::raw('now()')
        ]
    ]);
}
```

and here is the Message Model

```
class Message extends Model
{
    protected $dispatchesEvents = [
        "updated" => MessageUpdated::class
    ];
}
```

Comment: Whats the name of your event class?

Comment: @AdnanMumtaz its MessageUpdated

Comment: I think you are updating or creating a record using DB not wich elouqont that's why it is not creating the records.

Answer (score 0):

You can dispatch the event manually after inserting the row in the database. Look at [this section](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/events#dispatching-events) of the documentation. Basically you need to do something like this:

```
event(new YouEventClass($constructorParameters));
```